# Replacing Files in Google Drive UpdateMediaUpload

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I have no idea, why the content of the file will not be updated. Has anybody a hint?

The DriveFile.Id is valid. The source File is existing readable. Creating and deleting of files works fine. But not the Update.

I have read the migration from v2 to v3 uses generell the Http-PATCH Method for Update. Is this the answer.

I don't want to delete the file and create a new one.

```
public long DriveUpdateFile(string fileID, string filename, string description, string parent, string mimeType)
    {
        int lError = (int)Win32ErrorCode.ERROR_SUCCESS;
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(filename))
        {

            FilesResource.GetRequest get = m_Drive.Files.Get(fileID);
            File body = get.Execute();

            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(description))
                body.Description = description;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mimeType))
                body.MimeType = mimeType;

            // v3 Sematics
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parent))
            {
                body.Parents = new List<string>();
                body.Parents.Add(parent);
            }

            try
            {
                // File's content.
                using (System.IO.FileStream sr = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filename))
                {
                    FilesResource.UpdateMediaUpload request = m_Drive.Files.Update(body, body.Id, sr, body.MimeType);
                    request.Upload();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
                lError = e.HResult;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File does not exist: " + filename);
            lError = (int)Win32ErrorCode.ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND;
        }
        return (lError);
    }
```

Comment: Like you said, you can try the [Files:update](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/update) in Drive API v3. This method provides media upload functionality through two separate URIs. For media upload request use `PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/fileId` and for metadata-only request use `PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId`. Just take note that the request requires authorization with atleast one scope. Also check this [link](http://www.daimto.com/google-drive-api-c-upload/#Update) for sample code

Comment: hi KENdi the link refers to the daimto-samples. that is where i started. the daimto samples uses google-drive v2. i begin a new project and want to start with v3. there are two methods for update, like you said. first creates a UpdateRequest to patch metadata and second creates a UpdateMediaUpload to update content. the sample above works without any errors, but the content of the targetfile doesn't changes.

Comment: Problem is resolved see on Github: _After update to API v3 Update won't work_ [link](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/668) . Use only writable attributes of the attribute **Name** .

Answer (score 0):

Use scopes as below,

```
 string[] scopes = new string[] {

                                                 DriveService.Scope.Drive,
                                                 DriveService.Scope.DriveFile,
                                                 DriveService.Scope.DriveMetadata,
                                                 DriveService.Scope.DriveAppdata,
                                                 DriveService.Scope.DriveScripts
                };//DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly
```

and I check above code. the problem is ParentFolderId. please remove this line

```
 body.Parents = new List<string>();
 body.Parents.Add(parent);
```

direct assignment is not allowed in this scope. it should mention with request object like : `request.Parent ... bla bla`

and try.